# Retrieve Image from firebase in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The image picker works perfectly and I currently have the profileImageURL on firebase. I am not sure how to retrieve the image from firebase so it saves to the app. This is how I save it to firebase:

```
extension Profile: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        selectedPhoto = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

        var data = NSData()
        data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(selectedPhoto, 1.0)! as NSData
        // set upload path
        let filePath = "\(userId)/\("profileImage")"
        let metaData = StorageMetadata()
        metaData.contentType = "image/jpg"
        self.storageRef.child(filePath).putData(data as Data, metadata: metaData){(metaData,error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                return
            }else{
                //store downloadURL
                let downloadURL = metaData!.downloadURL()!.absoluteString
                //store downloadURL at database
                self.ref?.updateChildValues(["profileImage": downloadURL])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my attempt to retrieve it :

```
func loadUserProfileImage() {
        ref?.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if snapshot.hasChild("profileImage") {
                let filePath = "\(self.userId!)/\("profileImage")"
                self.storageRef.child(filePath).getData(maxSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) in

                    let thisPhoto = UIImage(data: data!)
                    selectedPhoto.image = thisPhoto

                })
            }
        })
    }
```